# In r, How can you read X number of fixed width flat files into Y data frames based on the file name?

Tags: r, for-loop, import, fixed-width

So I have 80 files that come in the file name format:

```
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF0.D00001.TO30000
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF0.D30001.TO60000
...
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF1.D30001.TO60000    
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF1.D30001.TO60000
...
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF9.D30001.TO60000    
P.A3588.ACO.CCLF9.D30001.TO60000
```

There are 80 fixed width text files: 8 parts for each of the 10 CCLF numbers (CCLF0,CCLF1,...,CCLF9). I want to be able to group by CCLF number, apply the column width vector, add column names, and bind the rows of the CCLF parts.

Below is what I've tried so far. It doesn't work, but gives an idea what I'm attempting.

```
filenames <- list.files(dataPath)
names <- substr(filenames,13,17)

CCLF1_width <- c(13,6,11,2,10,10,1,1,7,7,2,17,1,2,2,4,1,10,10,10,10,10,2,10,10,10,11,2,2,1,1,1)
CCLF2_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,4,10,5,11,6,10,10,24,17,2,2,2,2,2)
CCLF3_width <- c(13,11,2,2,7,10,11,6,10,10,1)
CCLF4_width <- c(13,11,2,1,2,7,11,6,10,10,7,1)
CCLF5_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,3,2,2,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,7,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,24,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1)
CCLF6_width <- c(13,10,11,2,10,10,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,2)
CCLF7_width <- c(13,11,11,2,10,2,20,1,1,24,9,2,20,13,2,10,10,12,9)
CCLF8_width <- c(11,2,3,5,10,1,1,3,2,2,10,10,10,30,15,40,1,1)
CCLF9_width <- c(11,11,10,10,12)
CCLF0_width <- c(11,11)

for (i in length(filenames)){
  assign(paste0(substr(filenames,13,17)),
  read_fwf(grepl("CCLF1",filenames),
  paste0(i,"_width")))
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain `column width`?

Comment: please provide a sample of output as well

Comment: Instead of a delimited text file, columns are split by a specified number of characters. So in the CCLF1_width, the first column has 13 characters and the second column has 6 characters (positions 14 though 19), third column has 11 characters (positions 20 through 31) and so on.

Comment: So you mean the 8 files that include "CLF0" have two columns, each with 11 characters? Similarly, the "CCLF9" files have 5 columns, of character widths 11, 11, 10, 10, and 12?

Comment: @ichbinallen, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider mapping through two equal length lists and iterate elementwise with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`):

```
cclf_files <- paste0("CCLF", seq(0:9))

cclf_widths <- list(
  CCLF0_width = c(11,11)
  CCLF1_width = c(13,6,11,2,10,10,1,1,7,7,2,17,1,2,2,4,1,10,10,10,10,10,2,10,10,10,11,2,2,1,1,1)
  CCLF2_width = c(13,10,11,2,10,10,4,10,5,11,6,10,10,24,17,2,2,2,2,2)
  CCLF3_width = c(13,11,2,2,7,10,11,6,10,10,1)
  CCLF4_width = c(13,11,2,1,2,7,11,6,10,10,7,1)
  CCLF5_width = c(13,10,11,2,10,10,3,2,2,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,7,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,24,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1)
  CCLF6_width = c(13,10,11,2,10,10,1,2,10,10,5,15,1,10,10,2,2,2,10,10,40,11,17,2)
  CCLF7_width = c(13,11,11,2,10,2,20,1,1,24,9,2,20,13,2,10,10,12,9)
  CCLF8_width = c(11,2,3,5,10,1,1,3,2,2,10,10,10,30,15,40,1,1)
  CCLF9_width = c(11,11,10,10,12)
)

proc_files <- function(f, w) {
    # RETRIEVE FILES WITH CURRENT CCF# IN NAME
    files <- list.files(path = "/path/to/cclf/files", pattern = f)
    print(files)

    # BUILD A LIST OF DFs FROM ALL FILES WITH CURRENT CCF#_width
    df_list <- lapply(files, function(x) {
                   tryCatch(read.fwf(x, widths=w), error = function(e) return(NA))
               })

    # ROW BIND ALL DFs TO FINAL FOR RETURN
    df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
}

# BUILD A NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES FOR EACH CCLF#
df_list <- setNames(Map(proc_files, cclf_files, cclf_widths), cclf_files)

df_list$CCLF0
df_list$CCLF1
df_list$CCLF2
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it may work, but I'm getting an error that my C stack usage is too close to the limit.  Some are pretty large files, so I may have to try a subset of the data. Will update tomorrow.

Comment: It may be my overlook. For *ccfl_files*, I used `paste` instead of `paste0` to avoid space separator. If issue persists we can run `tryCatch`.

Comment: It definitely does what I want, but get some errors due to the files. 

The lapply wouldn't accept just w as the argument so changed it to 

df_list <- lapply(files,function(x) read_fwf(x, fwf_widths(w)))

Since read_fwf uses a tibble, I have to use rbindlist from the data.table package instead. 

So inside the proc_files function, I changed to
df <- do.call(rbindlist,list(fill = TRUE),df_list)

When the I run the function it starts to load in the files, but stops with an error "Error in args <- lapply(args, enquote) : argument is not interpretatable as logical, so working on that

Comment: What do you mean `lapply` won't accept *w*? What is the error? With `rbindlist`, you do not need `do.call`. Just run it once `rbindlist(df_list)`. But to stay in tidyverse, use `df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)`. I mistakenly forgot that R has a built-in `read.fwf` (with period) vs. method in `readr` (with underscore). Try using base R's function which returns dfs and not tibbles. But from [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.1.1/topics/read_fwf), I see readr's function does have a *widths* argument.

Comment: I'm rerunning it on a subset of the data using the standard read.fwf w/o tidyverse, just takes a lot longer and doesn't show progress. 

The error I'm getting is: "Error in if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical "

Comment: See update with a `tryCatch` wrapper and a `print` of files so you can find which files are causing the issue. And for `do.call` to work, `colnames` must be the same and same length. How big are these files? GBs? For 80 in total, this should not be long. I may ask to see a sample of the fixed width files.

Comment: Now getting "Error in is_closure(x) : object 'files' not found.

The files only total around 1.8GB

Comment: Ah-ha! No files are being properly read in. Is your current working directory set to the CCLF files? Check `getwd()`. If not, pass in directory in *path* argument of `list.files()`. See edit. And again, the pattern searches for ANY file in directory with the current loop's *CCLF#* in its name (all caps).

Comment: I ended up getting it working! Thought I updated my comment, but guess it didn't go through. I removed the set_names function from outside the proc_files function and it worked just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! Glad it work out. Actually, you can still use `setNames` (no underscore) but pass in the character vector, *cclf_files* and not *files*. Tough to code these things without actual data!

Comment: Haha, you definitely nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with a for loop and a function.  I wrote the function `combine_fwf` to combine all fixed width files with a given CCLF number into a single dataframe.  The `list.files` line finds all files in the current working directory that contain CCLF where  is one of your numbers (0-9).  Then use `read.fwf` to read in that filename to a dataframe, cbind on the CCLF number and rbind it on to the overall result.

```
combine_fwf = function(CCLF_num, colwidths) {
  filenames = list.files(pattern = paste0("CCLF", CCLF_num))
  df_list = vector("list", length(filenames))
  for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
   df_list[[i]] = cbind.data.frame(CCLF_num, read.fwf(filenames[[i]], 
                                   colwidths)) 
  }
  return(do.call(rbind, df_list))
}

combine_fwf(2, c(12,6))
>>  CCLF_num           V1     V2
1        2 adsfasdfadsf 123123
2        2 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
3        2 adsfasdfadsf 123123
4        2 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
5        2 adsfasdfadsf 123123
6        2 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
> combine_fwf(1, c(12,6))
  CCLF_num           V1     V2
1        1 adsfasdfadsf 123123
2        1 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
3        1 adsfasdfadsf 123123
4        1 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
5        1 adsfasdfadsf 123123
6        1 lkjhlkjhlkjh  98098
```

Comment: @Parfait, what do you do instead?